# Image keyboard in android

Tags: android, keyboard

I need a keyboard consisting of images. How to send the images to respective applications.

Problems: 
 As keyboard it can be only linked to `EditText`. Emoji's as unicode. Images are not rendered in `EditText`

So basically what images are doing is share functionality in applications.

How to achieve this ?

Eg: I opened my whatsapp and changed keyboard to my custom keyboard. selected a image in that. It should send the image to the current person. Applicable to all applications.

Comment: I also tried doing this but didn't find any solution to this, as it is not necessary that every app is having code to handle images. It can only be done as it is done in messenger

Comment: You mean you can do it only in your own app ?

Comment: yes because how we can make sure that other apps have ability to handle images that we gonna post using our keyboard

Comment: Yeah. got it. Still looking for some clues.May be some intents or broadcast or something :(

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: No its not possible till now :( . You can only do that within your app.